# Different Discharge Dispositions in a Competing Risk Model

Tags: survival, competing-risks

I am building a data set on which to estimate, via regression, the impact of covariates on the cause-specific and subdistribution hazards for time to discharge from a hospital.  The main competing risks are death and discharge.  However, besides death, there are varying types of discharge that also preclude one another.  A patient may be discharged home, home with home health, or to a nursing facility.  Each of these different discharge dispositions is likely to be associated with a different mean time to discharge.  Is the correct method for treating the data to run the estimations with four competing risks?  Namely: death, discharge home, discharge home w/ home health, discharge to nursing facility.  As discharge is an outcome, I don't see a way of also including it as a covariate.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to distinguish among the different types of (non-death) discharge, then what you describe seems to be a competing-risks situation with 4 mutually exclusive outcomes (plus censoring for those not yet dead or discharged).

The [multi-state vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) of the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) illustrates how to approach this type of modeling. It also points out some potential limitations in Fine-Gray subdistribution hazards, as you envision. You have many choices to make, for example whether covariates have shared or separate associations with the 4 potential outcomes, so work carefully and try to avoid the temptation of using the observed outcomes when making those choices.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "avoid the temptation of using the observed outcome when making these choices"?  I have done quite a bit of reading on this type of modeling.  Papers and tutorials by Peter C. Austin have been exceptionally helpful, particularly [this one](https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/circulationaha.115.017719)

Comment: @Dan there's an all-too-human temptation to try out different models and see which one "works" better on your data. That's a particular risk in this type of situation, involving 4 different models with potentially different predictors/coefficients and a single data set. If you try out multiple models that way, there's a risk of overfitting, "significant" p-values that are erroneously calculated, and poor performance on new data. Frank Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) provide much guidance on how to avoid such traps.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  Covariate selection is the result of a thoughtful process by an expert committee where I work.  So they are all relevant to each discharge state and the risk of overfitting is low.

Comment: @Dan there is no substitute for expert application of subject-matter knowledge in this type of situation. I'm glad that you have such experts available to work with. Analysts sometimes aren't provided with useful subject-matter guidance.